# How to traverse a nested association without typing every model in the association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have

```
ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :modelb
end
ModelB < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :modelc
  belongs_to :modela
end
Modelc < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :modeld
  belongs_to :modelb
end
Modeld < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :modelc
end
```

I want to be able to write

```
modeld.modela
```

What's the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a chain using `has_one :through` (you could do implement `modela.modelds` similarly using `has_many :through`)

```
Modeld < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :modelc
  has_one :modelb, through: :modelc
  has_one :modela, through: :modelb
end
```

Comment: That only works in one direction. You can say `modela.modeld`, but not `modeld.modela`

Comment: You have it backwards. This will enable modeld.modela. With your models each modela has many modelbs and so on. So you couldnt make modela.modeld it would have to be modela.modelds. Besides you didnt say in your question that you wanted the invert

Comment: First of all, my apologies to @maxple. Everything he says is correct. I just implemented it incorrectly. I had the forward association, i.e., `has_many :modelc, through: :modelb` etc, but not the reverse as he suggested. What do you think about @sreang rathanak and @Leito answer. They all seem to do the same thing. Which is best and why?

Comment: @RamJet  Each of the other answers ends up calling `modeld.modelc.modelb.modela` under the hood. That requires 3 SQL queries. Using the `through:` option, though, combines those queries into one using `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried delegation?

```
delegate :modelb, to: :modelc
delegate :modela, to: :modelb
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is define method `modela` in model `Modeld`.

```
Modeld < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :modelc

  def modela
     self.modelc.try(:modelb).try(:modela)
  end
end
```